# Change a text color by using onPress on React Native

Tags: react-native

I have 3 TouchableHighLight in my view. It's all have text color is white. I want when I press one of buttons, text color will change green. But when I press it, all text color in button will change color green. Please help me.

Comment: Did you mean "just button you pressed change to green text instead of all buttons change to green text" ? Could you tell me this more clear? Thanks

Comment: you should share your code with the question so that one can help you with it.

Comment: @TungDuong Yes, that is. Just text color and button change

Answer (score 5):

In this case I would recommend using the Pressable API and its children prop.

```
      <Pressable
        children={({ pressed }) => (
          <Text style={{ color: pressed ? '#FF9E00' : '#222'}}>
            text
          </Text>
        )}/>
```

This way when clicking on one item, only that item changes color.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this, You can initialise the default color to be white in constructor, follow this for you other buttons,hope this will help.

```
<TouchableHighLight style = {{height: 20, width:20}} onPress = {()=> this.setState(colorCode: 'green')}>
<Text>{this.state.colorCode}</Text>
</TouchableHighLight>
```

Comment: Ya I use it but when I have three button, I just want one of the button change text color when I press it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use style attribute to change color of text. Like this

style={{color : this.state.colorCode}}

Also you can use default value without state

style={{color : this.state.colorCode || **"YOUR DEFAULT COLOR"**}}

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:
        this.state = {
            textColor: 'white'
        }

```
_onPressIn = () => {
    this.setState({
        textColor: 'green'
    });
}

_onPressOut = () => {
    this.setState({
        textColor: 'white'
    });
}
```

LOGIN

I have three button like this, I want when I click one of button just change text color, another text button don't change

Comment: <TouchableHighlight onShowUnderlay={this._onPressIn} onHideUnderlay={this._onPressOut} underlayColor='white' style={buttonStyles.buttonLogin}>
              
                            <Text style={[buttonStyles.textButtonLogin, { color: 
                    </TouchableHighlight>